# JBoss Deployment: Multiple apps under one profile

Tags: deployment, jboss

We have Multiple apps under one profile in JBoss server. Is there anyway to just deploy one app under the profile and not deploy the other apps under the same profile? It may be a valid situation where only one app under the profile is updated and needs re-deployment but other apps should continue to work as is and should not be re-deployed un-necessarily.

Thanks,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

You can use management console of JBoss to deploy/undeploy application. Go to `Deployemnts` tab, `Add/Remove/Replace` your particular application.

Comment: Thanks for the response